# How do you store a number entered through keypad buttons in D flip-flops?

Tags: digital-logic, logisim

[image: Circuit]

In the circuit, only **ONE** value from N0-N9 will be high.
So, only one of the OR gates will have a HIGH value. I need to use only the HIGH output from the OR gates output.

I tried using a multiplexer but that didn't quite work.

EDIT: The circuit is the store the last bit of a number(0-9). If, for example, N3 is pressed a 1 should be stored in a D-ff.

REPHRASED: **Please ignore the above**. Thanks guys for the feedback.I understand that my question was unclear.
My main objective is to make a calculator to add 4 bit numbers. The numbers to be added are inputted through a keypad. These numbers are stored in D flip-flops and then passed to a carry-lookahead adder. 
My question is how do I store the numbers inputted through the keypad in D flip-flops?

PS:
I am making this project in Logisim.
I am a freshman with some basic knowledge of digital electronics.

Comment: Use another OR gate on the outputs!

Comment: But then I need to know which pin (N0-N9) is HIGH. For example, if N7 is HIGH, I need only the bottom OR gate's output

Comment: There is nothing marked "D-ff" in your circuit. The question isn't very clear.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, even after your edit. Please try again.

Comment: You should give us a truth table. The textual explanations are very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Using the parts we have in CircuitLab, which are 2 and 3 input **OR**s and including some logic for getting an output tied to even/odd which was not in your initial question (for the initial question the circuit without the **AND** gates will do):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbkv6D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This version gives you an additional output tied to even or odd, but since you are not clear what you want to do with that, it's unclear how to help you. Clarity of thinking is required to make digital logic work, there's no cheat code.

If you need to "put a 1 or 0 somewhere" you can use **Out** to put the output of **While I'm getting odd** into whatever it is, since the presence of a signal at **Out** means a button was pressed, and if it's not odd, the output of **While I'm getting odd** is low, or 0, and thus the correct LSB for an even number. **AND2** is not even needed for that to work, though you might need to run **Out** through a couple of buffers or gates configured as buffers to get the timing right, depending on what you are using.

Comment: I answered the question you asked. Then you changed the question, though what you actually want is still clear as mud.

Comment: Well, you may have been been a bit fast. Answering such an unclear question without waiting for clarifications is like playing roulette. Anyway, I sympathise. +1.

Comment: It was clear (and trivial) as asked, before the first edit. The mud came with the edit.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me out. I am new to this subject so I had trouble phrasing my question. This explanation is gold. Ecnerwal thanks a ton!

Comment: To attack your further revised problem (and you'll learn better if **you** attack it) do much the same for each bit you need to store - which buttons set this bit, connect to similar logic. It will be rather messy.